# Which Hadoop 0.23.8 jars are needed for HBase 0.94.8

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I'm using Hadoop 0.23.8 pseudo distributed and HBase 0.94.8. My HBase master is failing with:

`Server IPC version 5 cannot communicate with client version 4`

I think this is because HBase is using hadoop-core-1.0.4.jar in its lib folder.

Now http://cloudfront.blogspot.in/2012/06/how-to-configure-habse-in-pseudo.html#.UYfPYkAW38s suggests I should replace this jar by copying:

```
 the hadoop-core-*.jar from your HADOOP_HOME ...
```

but there are no hadoop-core-*.jars in 0.23.8.

Will this process work for 0.23.8, and if so, which jars should I be using?
TIA!

Comment: I'm thinking maybe i just chuck in everything because of [this](http://hbase.apache.org/book/trouble.versions.html).

Answer (score 0):

I gave up with this and am using hadoop 2.2.0 which works well (ish) with HBase.